# How to add a View to a ScrollView at a specific position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` with a rectangle size of (414,736). I made a `ScrollView` 50 in width and 50 in height bigger than `UIView`. When I add `UIView` to `ScrollView`, `UIView` stays horizontally is *OK*, but in vertical it is located at the bottom of the `ScrollView`. So that my scrolling part is the top part. But I want `UIView` stay on the top part and the bottom part becomes the scrolling area.
How can I locate the `UIView` with a specific  location onto the `ScrollView`?
The following code shows how ScrollView is implemented.

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.drawChart];
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width+100,screenRect.size.height+50);
    self.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.564 green:0.439 blue:0.561 alpha:1];
    self.view=self.scrollView;
```

EDIT:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    //Database
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"RECORDS.db"]];
    //scroll view
    //
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.drawChart];
    CGRect frame = self.drawChart.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointZero;
    self.drawChart.frame = frame;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width+100,screenRect.size.height+50);
    self.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.564 green:0.439 blue:0.561 alpha:1];
        self.view=self.scrollView;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding the chartview to the scrollview

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.drawChart];
```

do the following:

```
CGRect frame = self.drawChart.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointZero;
self.drawChart.frame = frame;
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. self.drawChart.frame has (0,0) origin, even though I don't implement that.

Comment: 50 , that is the size I added for the ScrollView to be bigger than UIView.

Comment: can you maybe share the code in your viewcontroller somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93908/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-batuman).

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct. Just that I have a bug in drawchart that makes some offset.